# Extracting users in instagram "DIV" (in the likes of the photo)

Tags: html, instagram, extract, photo, imacros

**Hi everybody! i am new on imacros scripting and i am not a programmer.** I know very little about programming and I only adapt the command lines and analyze how they work, so I am making the program work.

I managed to learn about imacros at this time but still I need to explain step by step all detailed how to run the following program.

I make a video explain the problem.
**Please look at the cursor carefully and interpret how it works, it's simple**

https://youtu.be/tMbF3CawzRU

**My goal is as follows:** Open the profile of a user, select a photo and enter the "Like", within the "I like" enter the profile of each person to extract the username "URL".

**The problem is that my program only extracts 11 users (Those that appear as "DIV" in the instagram code).**

I designed another program which appears at the beginning of the video to demonstrate how it extracts perfectly but this is ONLY for FOLLOWERS - FOLLOWED.
Analyze the instagram code and this code allows me to "preload" the number of people I need and this makes the program WORK. Unlike the previous one (within the "LIKES" IT DOES NOT ALLOW ME "PRE LOAD" USERS and this limits the program (LOOP = 12-15-20-30-etc. It stops working with error # EANF #).

**First program ( VIDEO ) code: "FOLLOWES AND FOLLOWED (ONLY) "**

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:FPmhX<SP>notranslate<SP>_0imsa EXTRACT=HREF


SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

'Check EXTRACT
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO={{!VAR1}}
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

**MY GOALS CODE ( SECOND and the one that causes the problem ) " ON LIKES PHOTO "**

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:_7UhW9<SP>xLCgt<SP>qyrsm<SP>KV-D4<SP>fDxYl<SP>rWtOq EXTRACT=TXT

SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

'Check EXTRACT
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=https://www.instagram.com/{{!VAR1}}
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

Sorry for my bad English, it was translated with Google Translator.

**HELP ME PLEASE!**

Windows 10 x64

Chrome  Versión 76.0.3809.132 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

Chrome Imacros FREE 10.0.5

Firefox 69.0 (64-bit)

Firefox Imacros FREE 10.0.2.1450

( It works on both ) but i prefer firefox for Imacros.

I don't think they need anything more than this.
**I am looking to extract the number of users that I need (20-30-50 users within the likes of the photo)**
Apparently the DIV structure does not allow pre-loading users and I don't know how to solve this in order to extract the number of users that I want

**THANKS YOU FOR READ ME!**

Comment: (+1) from me for the good Quality of your Post, which is pretty rare for Qt's/Threads related to 'iMacros' on this Forum, especially from 1st time Posters... (The 'html' and 'photo' Tags are not really "needed", I would think...) - For those "interested", + parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?p=83440#p83436 - (Good luck further, I don't help myself for Social Media...)

Comment: Hi again chivracq, how are you, brother!
Could you help me a little? I would like to know if it is easy to do so and where I could "face" the problem: / thanks bro

Comment: If I use the "FOR" function of C - C ++ could it work?? I know how to program in very basic C ++